# Bulk Copy Commit Rows Without Errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a process that takes a lists and inserts it into a database using SQL bulk copy because of how particularly large this list can be. It works fine, checks constraints and all which is perfect. The problem is, if I have 10,000 records and one of those records has an error, I still want to commit the other 9,999. Is there a way to do this other than manually checking each constraint before SQL bulk copy or inserting one at a time? Seems tedious and slow which kind of defeats the point. Thanks.

```
var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints)
{ 
    DestinationTableName = obj.TableName 
};

var table = new DataTable();
copy.WriteToServer(table);
```

Comment: Could we see your code?  It sounds like you're performing the bulk copy as some sort of transaction, which would automatically roll back for any failure.

Comment: can you not specify a '-m' command in the bcp command? This way you can set the maximum number of errors before the import is cancelled.

Comment: Updated with code...not sure if it is going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Without setting a [batch size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize(v=vs.110).aspx) to 1 (which would defeat the purpose of the bulk copy) or pre-checking the data before the copy the normal way around this issue is you copy in to a temporary table with the same schema as your target table but with no constraints, remove the rows that would violate the constraints on insert, then do a normal insert from the temp table in to your live table.

```
const string _createTableString = "Create table #temp (/* SNIP */)";
const string _insertTableString = @"
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)
set @sql = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' SELECT * from #temp'
exec sp_executesql @sql";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(_createTableString, connection))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copy.DestinationTableName = "#temp";
        copy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(_insertTableString, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", obj.TableName)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to make sure that no SQL injections can sneak in via the name of the table passed in to `obj.TableName`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott. So I understand the general concept of the temp table. What I don't understand is how I would go about identifying which rows violate constraints and how to remove them in an efficient manner.

Comment: For that you would need to know what the constraints are and write up queries that identify and delete rows that violate them. You will not be able to use one function for all tables, you will need a separate function for each table so it can handle each constraint.